# Django: Image referenced in CSS showing locally but not on Heroku

Tags: css, django, heroku

I'm working in Django, deploying via Heroku, trying to use WhiteNoise for static assets.

I have a CSS file which refers to an image to use as a background:

```
body { background: white url("images/nyc.jpg") left top; }
```

When I load the page locally, the background image shows up perfectly.

However, when I deploy to Heroku (using git push from my local machine), the background image does NOT show up on the page.  I get this error message when I do the git push to Heroku:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
whitenoise.django.MissingFileError: The file 'multiblog/images/nyc.jpg' could not be found with <whitenoise.django.GzipManifestStaticFilesStorage object at 0x7fab5c4fb210>.
The CSS file 'multiblog/style.css' references a file which could not be found:
Please check the URL references in this CSS file, particularly any
relative paths which might be pointing to the wrong location.
```

Here are the relevant lines from my project level settings.py (happy to share more from it if needed):

```
# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/static-files/

BASE_DIR2 = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
STATIC_ROOT = 'staticfiles'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR2, 'static'),
]

# Simplified static file serving.
# https://warehouse.python.org/project/whitenoise/
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
from whitenoise.django import DjangoWhiteNoise

application = get_wsgi_application()
application = DjangoWhiteNoise(application)
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.django.GzipManifestStaticFilesStorage'
```

And [here's a picture of the file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kjw9c.png).

Answer (score 1):

In the screenshot you provided, the filename is `nyc.JPG`, while your code references `nyc.jpg`. Filenames are case-sensitive :)

Comment: In my case `background: white url("images/nyc.jpg") left top;` but i deleted the photo and uncommented this css styling referring to the image but i still receive the error `Please check the URL references in this CSS file, particularly any
relative paths which might be pointing to the wrong location.` any idea?

Answer (score -3):

Just run

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

see more : [collectstatic](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#collectstatic) , [Django and Static Assets](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets)

Comment: She reported an error that occurs while running collectstatic.